# for each JavaScript - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bucle-for

Tengo un array de objetos en un useState para ingredientes:

```
const [ingredientesSeleccionados, setIngredientesSeleccionados] = useState([
    {nombre: "Harina", peso: 2},
    {nombre: "Levadura", peso: 3.5}
    {nombre: "Azúcar", peso: 2.5}
]);
```

Hice un For each para sumar los pesos de ingredientes pero en lugar de sumar los concatena

```
const calcularTotal = (ingredientes) => {
        let sumaDeTotalDeIngredientes = 0;
        ingredientes.forEach((ingrediente) => {
            sumaDeTotalDeIngredientes += ingrediente.peso;
        });

         return sumaDeTotalDeIngredientes;
    };
```

y en lugar de salir: 8, sale 023.52.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidentemente los valores `peso` llegan como cadenas, por lo que, en lugar de sumarse se están concatenando.

#### Solución:

Podrías convertir las cadenas a numero usando [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

**Ejemplo:**

```
const calcularTotal = (ingredientes) => {
    let sumaDeTotalDeIngredientes = 0;
    ingredientes.forEach((ingrediente) => {
        // ACA convertimos a numero
        sumaDeTotalDeIngredientes += parseFloat(ingrediente.peso);
    });

    return sumaDeTotalDeIngredientes;
};
```

Comment: Gracias, era la solución!!